# strip whitespace and not new lines

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I am trying to remove whitespaces but not new lines in my text file in sublime text

I tried doing a find and replace of `\s` with `nothing`, but it also removes new lines, how can I remove whitespaces excluding new lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead:

```
(?!\n)\s
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `\n` by some unique string like `1@3@#` (which would not be present in your document) and then replace `\s` by `nothing` and then finally replace `1@3@#` by `\n`